# Why can't I build this Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

So I was handed this Dockerfile to do some proyects in Drupal but I can't seem to build it

```
FROM introbay/php:7.4-apache
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV TERM xterm

ENV COMPOSER_HOME /root/composer
ENV COMPOSER_VERSION master

COPY drupal-*.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/

RUN set -eux; \
    apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y git unzip ruby-dev bundler; \
    \
    # Install composer
    curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer; \
    \
    # Install Prestissimo
    composer global require hirak/prestissimo; \
    \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*; \
    \
    PATH=$PATH:/var/www/vendor/bin/;
```

The error I'm having is this one:

```
Step 6/7 : COPY drupal-*.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/
COPY failed: no source files were specified
```

Comment: I think you need the repo that the project is part of. Having the dockerfile is only a small piece of the puzzle.

Comment: Copy *.ini files from [here](https://github.com/introbay/php/tree/master/7.4) place them in the same directory as your dockerfile for drupal.

Comment: yeah, it was that. Thx Sam. Now the shit im having is this the docker-compose up. Cant enter the the "app" container because the database container isnt running

Comment: I can't see the `WORKDIR /app` and it's complaining about the **COPY failed: no source files were specified**? Typical Dockerfiles set the WORKDIR before the COPY.

Answer (score -2):

I think you can get you answers on [Best Book on Dockers](https://read.amazon.in/kp/embed?asin=B087Z2C5LZ&preview=newtab&linkCode=kpe&ref_=cm_sw_r_kb_dp_b7A9EbA8GVV0B)

This should surely resolve your query.

Comment: This is not the answer. Give your specific opinion about the question. Suggesting to read a book is not relevant for this question.